# CURL ошибка при отправке параметров GET

Tags: php, curl, get

Отправляю GET запрос CURLом, для добавления данных в гугл диск. Если ввожу данные в запросе вручную(конкретные строки), то все ок, запрос проходит и добавляет данные в таблицу, при этом если указываю переменные в запросе то выдает ошибку:

> 400. That’s an error.
>
> Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.

Вот код отправки:

```
if ($curl = curl_init()) {
    $urls = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/id-table/exec?p1='.$action.'&p2='.$date.'&p3='.$time.'&p4='.$operator.'&p5='.$vx.'&p6='.$chanel.'&p7='.$phone.'&p8='.$type.'&p9='.$reason.'&p10='.$name.'&p11='.$cities.'&p12='.$broker;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $urls);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    echo $out;
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучшим вариантом было бы пользоваться функцией http_build_query, которая именно для решения вашей проблемы предназначена:

```
$urls = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/id-table/exec?'.http_build_query([
    'p1' => $action,
    'p2' => $date,
    'p3' => $time,
    // и так далее
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема была в пробелах и в русских символах, решил вот так:

```
urlencode($переменная)
```